# Create Multi page PDF in Angular Using jsPDF and html2Canvas

Tags: angular, pdf-generation, jspdf, html2canvas

I have an [application which has a list of (3) items on left and their respective previews](https://stackblitz.com/edit/generate-all-screens-pdf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

There's a `Generate PDF` button on click of which should download a PDF with all the (3) previews properly.

I tried traversing through all the previews and when a list Item is previewed, I am collecting the DOM into an `array (service property)`. When traversal over all the items is completed, I looped over the collection `array (service property)` and tried generating the PDF.

I expected a **PDF to be generated with all the listed item previews captured.**
But the issue is **a PDF having only one blank page is generated** which is not expected.

I tried using 2 different methods to capture the HTML but in vain.

1. using traditional `document.getElementById()`
2. using `@ViewChild()` (stackblitz example contains this implementation now)

What is being missing here for this requirement to be accomplished?